# Using Spring java , can you able to save instance fields thread-safely?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-safety

Is it possible to batch requests together, so they are done safely.

For example:

Trying to save all buying/selling orders to group each users orders within 10 minutes. This means you need to store in memory which each user uses.

So you have a hashmap of order builders saved within the service. I think this won't be thread safe due to the Maps.

A simple example (Not working java code), just a rough example

```
@Service
public class OrderService
{
    Map<User,OrderRequestBuilder> builders = new HashMap<User,OrderRequestBuilder>()
    Map<User,Timer> timers =  new HashMap<User,Timer>(();
    public void addOrder( User user , BuyOrder order)
         if (!builders.containsKey(user)){
              builders.put(user, new OrderRequestBuilder().withUser(user);
         }
         OrderRequestBuilder builder = builders.get( user );
         builder.withAddOrder( order);
         builders.put(builder);
         if (!timers.containsKey(user){
             Timer t = new Timer();
             t.schedule( new TimerTask(){
                   public void run(){
                      sendOrder(user)
                   }},600000
         }
    }

    // Runs at a fixed time for a specific account, scheduled
    public void sendOrder(User user){
         timers.remove(user);
         sendService.send( builders.remove(user).build() );
         builders.put(user, new OrderRequestBuilder().withUser(user);

    }

    public void sellOrder( User user , SellOrder order)
         if (!builders.containsKey(user)){
              builders.put(user, new OrderRequestBuilder().withUser(user);
         }
         OrderRequestBuilder builder = builders.get( user );
         builder.withSellOrder( order);
         builders.put(builder);
         if (!timers.containsKey(user){
             Timer t = new Timer();
             t.schedule( new TimerTask(){
                   public void run(){
                      sendOrder(user)
                   }},600000
         }
    }
```

}

Comment: A Hashmap would definitely not work in your use case.  But have you considered using something like a ConcurrentHashMap?  They are thread safe.  My bigger concern is that I don't see any removes from the hash map meaning that there might be repeated order processing everytime the timertask runs.

Comment: This was just a rough post up. However it should change, as newOrderRequestBuilder is put upon sending, and so won't be repeated order processing.